# iOS Provisioning Profile not installing on one particular device

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning-profile, udid, ios-provisioning

I recently have distributed an app for testing, and the test team are having a problem installing the app, more specifically the provisioning profile associated with the app.

They are using an iPhone 4 (iOS 5.1.1) and are getting "Could not install the provisioning profile due to an unknown error"

I am used to seeing this when a UDID is not registered against the profile which is trying to be installed, but they are adamant that they have supplied the correct UDID. In terms of the profile, both looking at provisioning on the iOS Dev account, and opening in a text editor confirms that the UDID that has been supplied is definitely present.

My question is, are there any known issues (other than wrong UDID supplied) which could cause this to occur on a device, even if that device is authorised to install that particular provisioning profile?

Thanks

Comment: You say "test team" which implies more than one device and person. Does it work okay on another device?

Comment: Yep its functional on all of their other devices

Comment: Have they have chosen "use this device for development" in iTunes?

Comment: Also, is this a device they haven't used for your apps before? It could be that you provided them with a wild card profile previously that didn't include this device and it's maybe that profile that's allowing your app to run on the other devices?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (Seriously.)

Answer (score 21):

This won't answer your question because your problematic device is iOS-5.1, but it may help lots of other people:

Another possible issue since iOS7 is where did you find UDID. [As Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/index.html):

> In iOS 7, apps that are already on the store or on users’ devices that call this removed API will no longer be returned the UDID. Instead, -[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] will return a 40-character string starting with FFFFFFFF, followed by the hex value of -[UIDevice identifierForVendor].

Consequetly, check the UDID your client/collaborator sends to you: if it begins with FFFFFFFF, thats a wrong one.

The only & unique method to get UDID under iOS7 is to plug your device to a computer, launch iTunes (or Xcode) and copy the displayed UDID.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the UDID which is generated programmatically gives a random alphanumeric code from iOS 7. So to make sure you are using the right one, connect it to iTunes and then copy the UDID.

Answer (score 0):

There may be few reasons behind that because information is not enough so i can just guess -

- If you're getting any **boot strap error** in console then delete app from device then switched OFF your device then ON and try again.
- May be in your device there is already an app having same profile so your app would overwrite on previous one and new app would not be install.
- Last It might be provisioning profile issue. Make it again.