# Unusable UDID in new ios7 (with FFFFFFFF prefix)

Tags: ios7, udid

I need to register new device because I need mobileprovision. I can't use mobileprovision because `UDID` has `FFFFFFFF` on start. I think it is wrong `UDID`.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes. The "FFFFFFFF" UDIDs are wrong. This seems due to the fact that the UDID is now considered a Privacy Topic and thus Apps are not allowed anymore to retrieve them... and iOS returns an obfuscated UDID if called and precedes the first digits with FFFFFFFF. So I guess some of your clients got the UDID via an App on the device.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032885/2580805
"The only & unique method to get UDID under iOS7 is to plug your device to a computer, launch iTunes (or Xcode) and copy the displayed UDID."

But I have to add: there are at least two more options:

1. Our testers that provided their UDID by registering their devices via TestFlightApp.com also got non-FFFFFFFF UDIDs that worked.
2. Testers can surf with their device's Safari to: http://udid.io - this site installs a (temporary!) profile on the device which allows it to show the user a working UDID for copy & paste.

Answer (score 4):

you can use to get the proper UDID of the device(s) the followings:

- *iTunes* application;
- the *Xcode* Organiser option;

or online:

- http://get.udid.io (the actual device needs to open this site);

Answer (score 1):

get UDID through `Organizer` or `iTunes`. if you are getting it through 3rd party software, that might be wrong.

For Organizer, press `Command+Shift+2` on `XCode`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid installing iTunes on Windows by using USBDeview, which is less than 200k in size. The "Serial Number" column under USBDeview is the UDID.